# Changing the validator of an embedded form field

Tags: symfony1

I have this schema:

```
propel:
  autor:
    id: ~
    nombre: { type: varchar, size: 255, required: true }

  libro:
    id: ~
    autor_id:   { type: integer, size: 11, foreignTable: autor,
foreignReference: id}
    titulo:     { type: varchar, size: 255 }
    paginas:    { type: varchar, size: 255, required: true }
```

and this form class:

```
class AutorForm extends BaseAutorForm
{
  public function configure()
  {
    $this->embedRelation('Libro');
  }

public function foo()
{
    $this->validatorSchema['Libro']['newLibro1']['paginas'] = new
sfValidatorPass();
    return $this;

}
}
```

I'm calling foo() after the bind() (inside processForm()).

After submiting the Auto-Libro form, if I don't insert anything in the
field 'paginas' of the first embedded form (Libro), it shows
"Required".

But.. why if paginas has a validator-pass?

**EDIT**: after matt's answer, this is my code:

```
var_dump($this->embeddedForms['Libro']->validatorSchema['newLibro1']['paginas']);
$this->embeddedForms['Libro']->validatorSchema['newLibro1']['paginas'] = new sfValidatorPass(array('required' => false));
var_dump($this->embeddedForms['Libro']->validatorSchema['newLibro1']['paginas']);
```

It prints this:

```
object(sfValidatorString)[152]
  protected 'requiredOptions' => 
    array
      empty
  protected 'defaultMessages' => 
    array
      'required' => string 'Required.' (length=9)
      'invalid' => string 'Invalid.' (length=8)
      'max_length' => string '"%value%" is too long (%max_length% characters max).' (length=52)
      'min_length' => string '"%value%" is too short (%min_length% characters min).' (length=53)
  protected 'defaultOptions' => 
    array
      'required' => boolean true
      'trim' => boolean false
      'empty_value' => string '' (length=0)
      'max_length' => null
      'min_length' => null
  protected 'messages' => 
    array
      'required' => string 'Required.' (length=9)
      'invalid' => string 'Invalid.' (length=8)
      'max_length' => string '"%value%" is too long (%max_length% characters max).' (length=52)
      'min_length' => string '"%value%" is too short (%min_length% characters min).' (length=53)
  protected 'options' => 
    array
      'required' => boolean true
      'trim' => boolean false
      'empty_value' => string '' (length=0)
      'max_length' => int 255
      'min_length' => null

object(sfValidatorPass)[196]
  protected 'requiredOptions' => 
    array
      empty
  protected 'defaultMessages' => 
    array
      'required' => string 'Required.' (length=9)
      'invalid' => string 'Invalid.' (length=8)
  protected 'defaultOptions' => 
    array
      'required' => boolean true
      'trim' => boolean false
      'empty_value' => null
  protected 'messages' => 
    array
      'required' => string 'Required.' (length=9)
      'invalid' => string 'Invalid.' (length=8)
  protected 'options' => 
    array
      'required' => boolean false  <<<<<<<<<<<< FALSE <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
      'trim' => boolean false
      'empty_value' => null
```

The problem is still the same: when i try to submit the form, the field 'paginas' is still required. Why?

sf 1.4/propel 1.6

Javi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost all validators, including the sfValidatorPass, default to required=true.

I believe the sfValidatorPass doesn't mean "it always passes validation" it means "pass the submitted value through without cleaning it or checking anything."

> sfValidatorPass is an identity validator. It simply returns the value unmodified.

So I think you can just do

```
$this->validatorSchema['Libro']['newLibro1']['paginas'] = new 
    sfValidatorPass(array('required' => false));
```

Comment: Thanks, I wrote the line you say but it still doesn't work...I have edit my question to add more clues.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know. How are your form fields organized in the actual submission? -- is it possible that the paginas that gets submitted is not hitting your validatorPass, but is hitting the default validator in BaseAutorForm?